# Virtual environment with python 3.7.4 not created in Anaconda 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, python-venv

I am typing following command in Anaconda Powershell Prompt:

```
conda create -n test_env python=3.7.4 anaconda
```

During installation of packages not all packages are installed and finally the following response is issued:

```
CondaMultiError: RuntimeError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object')
```

The current distribution of Anaconda installed is 2019.03 with Python 2.7 (I tried to install 2019.07 distribution with latest Python initially, but installation was failing with a response "Failed to create menus"). This is corporate PC behind a proxy. I inserted proxy settings into conda.rc file and it's working fine in the sense that I can install any individual package via anaconda powershell prompt. 
What may be the reason for inability to create a virtual environment with newer version of python, may you please offer some suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you add the verbosity flag in the conda create command: `conda create -vv -n test_env python=3.7.4 anaconda` to see more information?

Comment: ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an erro in your proxy configuration. Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory, any environment variables ending in '_PROXY' and any other system-wide proxy configuration settings

Answer (score 0):

use this command:

```
conda create -n envname python=3.7
```